# htacces remove language parameter then redirect to browser's language

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry if duplicated, but I can't find the solution.

My current url is: domain.com/index.php?lang=en
I want to the url is looks like this: domain.com/en
Then if the browser's language is english, redirect to the english version.

I try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?language=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /en [L]
```

But doesn't work.
Please help.